# Apply a pandas window function to a reversed MultiIndex level?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I need to get an `.expanding` calculation on a MultiIndex DataFrame.  But I need it to run in reverse.  Here's a sample DataFrame:

```
np.random.seed(456)
j = [(a, b) for a in ['A','B','C'] for b in pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=5, freq='W')]
i = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(j, names=['Name','Num'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(15), i, columns=['Vals'])
df.loc[df['Vals'] < 0] = np.nan
```

And here is an example of what I want to do for each of the level-0 index values:

```
k = df.loc['A']
k['Missing'] = k[::-1].isnull().expanding().sum() # Expanding-sum on reversed level-1
```

This produces the correct results for that one top-level value `'A'`:

```
                Vals  Missing
Num                          
2018-01-07       NaN      2.0
2018-01-14       NaN      1.0
2018-01-21  0.618576      0.0
2018-01-28  0.568692      0.0
2018-02-04  1.350509      0.0
```

But how do I get that to apply to all top-level index values, so I can set `df['Missing'] =`?

I was trying things of the form `df.groupby('Name')[::-1].isnull().expanding().sum()` ... but I can't get a functional form that allows the level-1 index to be reversed for the calculation.

What is a pandaic expression to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: After grouping we have to strip the top level off the MultiIndex before working on the inner set:

```
df['Missing'] = df.groupby('Name').apply(
        lambda x: x.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)[::-1].isnull().expanding().sum()
    )
```

I.e., we `groupby('Name')`, and then for each group the lambda expression strips the level-0 index via `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`, at which point we can use the remaining DataFrame in reverse order: `x[::-1]`.